# Given a BytesIO buffer, generate img tag in html

Tags: python, html, image, buffer

Is it possible to generate a functional image tag in html from a BytesIO buffer? I'd like to do something along these lines:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg') 
import pylab
import Image
import io

temp_data = {'x':[1,2,3],'y':[2,4,5]}
pylab.plot(temp_data['x'], temp_data['y'])

img_buffer = io.BytesIO()
pylab.savefig(img_buffer, format = 'png')
img_buffer.seek(0)

img_tag = "<img src='data:image/png;base64,'" + img_buffer.getvalue() + "</img>"
```

May be necessary to re-format the value of the buffer in some way, or to change the content of the 'src' data. Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Python2

Towards the end of the code above, do this

```
import base64
img_tag = "<img src='data:image/png;base64," + base64.b64encode(img_buffer.getvalue()) + "'/>"
```

#### Python3

For this to work in python3 you will need to decode the bytes variable generated from `base64.b64encode` using `str.decode` method into a string as follows

```
import base64
str_equivalent_image = base64.b64encode(img_buffer.getvalue()).decode()
img_tag = "<img src='data:image/png;base64," + str_equivalent_image + "'/>"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with `Flask`, then you can return the `UTF-8` format of the image and play with it.

```
figfile = BytesIO()
plt.savefig(figfile, format='png')

plt.clf() # this will clear the image

figfile.seek(0)
figdata_png = base64.b64encode(figfile.getvalue())
return figdata_png.decode('UTF-8')
```

Remember to mention it in `<img/>` tags. This is to implement in `Flask`.